# A normal $p$-group of $G$ is contained in each Sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I have shown that if $S\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$, then $N\cap S\in \text{Syl}_p(N)$.

After that I am asked to show that if $N$ is also a $p$-group then $N\trianglelefteq S$, i.e., that a normal $p$-group of $G$ is contained in each Sylow subgroup.

Could you maybe give me some hints how we could show that?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The p-Sylow subgroups are conjugated. $N$ is contained in the Sylow subgroup $S$, if $S'$ is another Sylow $p$-subgroup, $S'=gSg^{-1}$, but $N\subset S$ implies that  $gNg^{-1}\subset S'$, since $N$ is normal, $gNg^{-1}=N$. thus $N\subset S'$.

Comment: I got stuck...  What is $N'$ ? Do you mean $S'$ at the end?

Comment: Why do we have that $N$ is contained in the Sylow subgroup $S$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Consequences

Comment: Ah ok... I see... We know that there is another $p$-Sylow subgroup $S'$, since all the $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate, right?

Comment: Also, having shown that $N\subseteq S'$, how do we conclude that $N\trianglelefteq S$ ?

Comment: $N$ is contained in $S$, you want to show that it is contained in every other Sylow subgroup. Let $S'$ be another group, $S'$ is conjugated to $S$...

Comment: I got it!! Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

First part: since $N \trianglelefteq G $, $NP$ is  subgroup of $G$ and $[NP:P]=[N:N \cap P]$ (use that $NP/N \cong P/(N \cap P))$. Since $P \in Syl_p(G)$ and $[NP:P]$ divides $[G:P]$, the index $[N:N \cap P]$ is not divisible by $p$. This implies that the $p$-subgroup $N \cap P \in Syl_p(N)$.

Conversely, if $Q \in Syl_p(N)$, then the $p$-subgroup $Q$ is contained in some $P \in Syl_p(G)$ (this is a well-known lemma). Hence $Q \subseteq N \cap P$. But we just showed that $N \cap P \in Syl_p(N)$, whence $Q=N \cap P$. In other words, all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ arise by intersecting those of $G$ with $N$.

Comment: Could you give me a hint for the second part? As in the answer of Tsemo Aristide, we can show that $N$ is a subgroup of each $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, right? But is this equivalent to say that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $S$ ?

Comment: If $N$ is a normal $p$-subgroup then it must be contained in any Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$: look at $SN$, which is a subgroup since $N$ is normal. It is also a $p$-subgroup ($|SN|=\frac{|S| \cdot |N|}{|S \cap N|}$, which is a power of $p$). But since $S \subseteq SN$, and $|G:S|$ is prime to $p$, we must have $SN=S$, meaning $N \subseteq S$. The normality of $N$ in $G$ implies the normality of $N$ in $S$ now. Not the other way around.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: OK, you are welcome. Do not forget to tick one of the answers as being the right/preferred one, otherwise it remains "open", against policies here on this site.